SQL Server ceases to function due to insufficient memory
I have used a locally installed instance of SQL Server for my software development work on various laptops over the past 16 years.
About 3 weeks ago, I started using a new laptop and almost immediately began experiencing a handful of timeouts and other errors when my apps try to query SQL Server, making it barely usable.
The most common error I encounter is like this:

Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=17; handshake=357; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=5; [Post-Login] complete=14408;

Looking in the Windows Application log, I can see entries coinciding with these timeouts, suggesting this is a memory-related issue:

There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
The client was unable to reuse a session with SPID 75, which had been reset for connection pooling. The failure ID is 29. This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing. Check the error logs for failed operations immediately before this error message.

This is surprising to me because in 16 years, I have never encountered this issue on any other laptop, and this one has at least twice as much RAM (16 GB) as any I've ever had before.
Task manager shows my memory usage at or around 95% most of the time, so the use of physical memory is high, but I would have thought the system would page out to virtual memory if there wasn't enough physical memory. On my other laptops, SQL Server has continued to function even when memory usage was high.
What can I do to troubleshoot/solve this problem? I don't mind if SQL server performance is sub-optimal due to using virtual memory, but I can't use it if it ceases to function entirely.
System details:
Current laptop

OS: Windows 11 Pro
RAM: 16 GB
SQL Server:

Community Edition 16.0.1115.1
Maximum server memory: 2000 MB



Previous laptop

OS: Windows 10 Pro
RAM: 8GB
SQL Server:

Community Edition 15.0.2110.4
Maximum server memory: 2147483647 MB




An SQL server will eat all the available memory it can get. Usually limiting the amount of memory solves problems like these. Have you tried limiting the memory to say... 8GB?

When you configured your local instance, did you specific an affinity mask and a memory cap? If you don't set any limits, SQL Server will use all available resources.

@spikey_richie great minds think alike. lol

Both machines had the same version installed? Post the configuration of the SQL Server.

@LPChip When I started encountering this issue, I tried limiting the memory to 2000 MB, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. To be clear, my main issue is not that SQL server is occupying too many resources, but that it stops functioning when enough physical memory is not available.

@spikey_richie When I started encountering this issue, I tried limiting the memory to 2000 MB, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. To be clear, my main issue is not that SQL server is occupying too many resources, but that it stops functioning when enough physical memory is not available. I'm not sure what an affinity mask is and haven't done anything with that, nor have I ever done so on a previous machine.

@Ramhound Previous version was 15.0.2110.4, current is 16.0.1115.1. Both are community edition. I have now added this information to my question.

The Stack Overflow questions on this error suggest this is a code problem, specifically, one with ODBC or System.Data.SqlClient. You should double check the configuration of the server is identical.

BTW, I find Intelligent standby list cleaner from Wagnardsoft, https://www.wagnardsoft.com/content/Intelligent-standby-list-cleaner-ISLC-v1033-Released , helpful in freeing memory for long-running tasks (e.g., moving many books in Calibre). It might help with SQL Server issue... but should not be needed. Can you use connection other than ODBC??

@DrMoishePippik I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm actually using ADO.NET, not ODBC, and the software I develop is able to query its backing database just fine across dozens of production environments for over 10 years. It's only my new laptop where this issue is happening. And the queries where it's failing aren't anything hefty - just simple SELECTs on a tiny database.

After you change the memory allocation, you have to restart SQL Server. In the Memory tab of the Server Properties in SSMS, you'll see the Configured Values and Running Values radio buttons at the bottom. Check that Running Values match Configured Values. The affinity mask in the Processors tab specifies how many processor cores to use. You would usually leave CPU0 unassigned for SQL, so that the OS has at least 1 core it can use. If you don't set limits, SQL Server will take everything it can.

@JLRishe, perhaps test switching from ADO.NET to ODBC or other connection? Could be an issue in Windows 11, or another version of DOTNET needs to be tried,

When you have the memory issue, it might be worth capturing the output of RAMMap:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap
Just a screenshot of the first "use counts" tab would be useful to add to the question. Thanks

Dont just look for a memory problem. The error message is pretty generic and i would take "This error may have been caused by an earlier operation failing." as the leading message. Failure ID 29 is "RedoLoginException". An article at this url https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-support-blog/breaking-down-18056/ba-p/317548 does a good job at showing how to debug.
